# How to download and save audio and video in wp7 mediaLiabrary?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mediaelement, media-library

Can you please tell me how to save or store sample audio and vidio into mediaLibrary.From my application if i long press on a picture i get a save picture option that saves the picture under saved pictures category in MediaLibrary. Similarly how do i save a mp3 and mp4 file.

I am able to downloadcontent and play the audio on emulator directly but not able to save any mp3 file from the web onto the MediaLibrary. Is there any other way to add songs to MediaLibrary?

Please Help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Phone 7 API does not allow saving audio and video to the Media library, only on the isolated storage of the application itself.

This is in contrast to Pictures, which like you said you can save to the Media library.

Comment: :okay so i am not able to save audio or video to my phone? because isolated stroge save file inside the application and i want to save this file in my phone so when my internet is off so i can listen a song.my concept is like when i want to listen s song so no need to open application i directly listen a song

Comment: Saving on isolated storage DOES save to your phone, just no the media library. You'll have to open the application to listen to audio and video files you downloaded from the application, but you won't need internet connection for that as they are on your phone. See here: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage

Comment: :thanks for replay but i want save this file in my phone folder like (i.e sdk or phone memory).My concept is ones i completed download than after this file is save in my phone memory or sdk.when i want listen this song or video so no need to open application i just open folder and play sang.this is concept and one of my friend is done this thing in android and ios.but i dont know how it is possible in wp?

Comment: I'll write this again, maybe I was not clear: This is NOT POSSIBLE with the windows phone 7 SDK and APIS. You CANNOT save an audio or video to the media library, or phone memory as you call it. Maybe this is available in Android, but not in windows phone since you don't have complete access to the file system.

Comment: :thanks actully i tryed much for finding this functionality but not get succes than  i think that this is not possible in wp7.but i am not sure and finally you give me surety.